# Should I recommend deletion for answers that are bad because of content?

Tags: discussion, review, low-quality-posts

So I just reviewed a "low quality post", and found that although the post was relatively OK (the intent was clear enough) it was just plain wrong - as pointed out by various comments.

So my question is: Should I recommend such answers for deletion, or just downvote it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrong things should be downvoted, possibly with a comment about what's wrong. Deletion is for things that aren't trying to be an answer, not for wrong information.

Comment: But in the Low quality queue you can't vote it down, only looks good or recommend for deletion

Comment: You can always "Looks good" and separately downvote it.